# sscanf get the value of the remaining string

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

I have a String which looks like this:

```
"HELLO 200 Now some random text\n now more text\t\t"
```

I try to get the HELLO, the 200, and the remaining string. Unfortunately the string may contain `\n`'s and `\t`'s so i cannot use `%[^\n\t]`.

I tried the following approach:

```
char message[MESSAGE_SIZE], response[RESPONSE_SIZE];
int status;
sscanf (str, "%s %d %[^\0]", message, &status, response);
```

afterwards the variables are

```
message = "HELLO", status = 200, response = "HELLO 200 Now some random text\n now more text\t\t"
```

but this includes `HELLO 200` in the response string (which should not be there). Is there a way to achieve this with `scanf` directly, without strtok?

Comment: Now that you've reached your goal by using `"%s %d %[^\0]"`, what's your question now?

Comment: Did not reach my goal, the response does not have the desired value. Response should be "Now some random text\n now more text\t\t" without the HELLO and status code

Comment: On my computer, `response` is exactly "No some random text\n now more text\t\t"

Comment: not on my machine with GCC 5.3.0

Comment: I'm using code::blocks with GCC 4.7.1. There are two warnings: `main.c|11|warning: no closing ']' for '%[' format [-Wformat]|` and  `main.c|11|warning: embedded '\0' in format [-Wformat-contains-nul]|`. The first one seems interesting.

Comment: @sunqingyao It might seem puzzling but once you think about it, it'll make sense. `sscanf` reads the format string (first argument) until a NUL-terminator (`'\0'`). In case of `"%s %d %[^\0]"`, there is a `\0` embedded in the string. This explains the second warning. `sscanf` therefore sees only `"%s %d %[^"`. Now you'll understand the first warning. I don't know if that string invokes Undefined Behavior. So, [I've asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35102559/3049655) related to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use scanset for the whole range of the `unsigned char` type:

```
char message[MESSAGE_SIZE], response[RESPONSE_SIZE];
int status;
*response = '\0';
sscanf(str, "%s %d %[\001-\377]", message, &status, response);
```

Plus you should always check the return value from `sscanf`.  If there is only white space after the number, the third specifier will not match anything and `sscanf` will return `2`, leaving `response` unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

The %n specifier will capture the number of characters used in a scan. This should get the number of characters used in scanning the first values then strcpy from that index.

```
int used;
sscanf (str, "%s %d %n", message, &status, &used);
strcpy ( response, &str[used]);
```