# What happens if I forget to close a scanset?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

Suppose I forgot to close the right square bracket `]` of a scanset. What will happen then? Does it invoke Undefined Behavior?

Example:

```
char str[] = "Hello! One Two Three";
char s1[50] = {0}, s2[50] = {0};
sscanf(str, "%s %[^h", s1, s2); /* UB? */
printf("s1='%s' s2='%s'\n", s1, s2);
```

I get a warning from GCC when compiling:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:11:5: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format [-Wformat=]
     sscanf(str, "%s %[^h", s1, s2); /* UB? */
```

and the output as

```
s1='Hello!' s2=''
```

I've also noticed that the `sscanf` returns 1. But what exactly is going on here?

I've checked the C11 standard, but found no information related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excellent!  You should file a defect report for C11!

Here is the relevant part in C11 7.21.6.2

> ... *The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the format string, up to and including the matching right bracket (]). The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (^), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket.*

A strict interpretation of *The characters between the brackets* is that in the absence of a closing bracket there are no such characters, but in the presence of `^` as the first character after `[`, it would be inconsistent.  `gcc` is kind enough to point the probable error in the source code.  The actual behavior is determined by the C library implementation, but does not seem to be specified in the C Standard.  As such it is a form of undefined behavior that IMHO should really be documented as such in the Standard.

Comment: Thanks! I suggest that you file a defect report as I don't know where to go and how to do it.

Comment: I sent an email to Daniel Plakosh, the C working group's secretary, I'll keep you posted on the proceedings.

Comment: @chqrlie surfaced again today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66013007/918959 - did you get any response? :D