# Why can a null character be embedded in a conversion specifier for scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting my results, but:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[32] = "";
    int x;
    x = scanf("%31[^\0]", buf);
    printf("x = %d, buf=%s", x, buf);
}
$ printf 'foo\n\0bar' | ./a.out
x = 1, buf=foo
```

Since the string literal `"%31[^\0]"` contains an embedded null, it seems that it should be treated the same as `"%31[^"`, and the compiler should complain that the `[` is unmatched.  Indeed, if you replace the string literal, clang gives:

`warning: no closing ']' for '%[' in scanf format string [-Wformat]`

Why does it work to embed a null character in the string literal passed to scanf?

-- EDIT --

The above is undefined behavior and merely happens to "work".

Comment: Maybe the compiler (the static analyzer of it) is just not "trained" to interpret the `\0` inside string literals? It does not have to have a full format string interpreter.

Comment: I would say it doesn't work, for the reason you state.

Comment: What C library? glibc? Most probably when `]` is missing, it continues parsing. Still, it's your fault - [it's ub](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p13). I get `x = 0, buf=` and it checks out with [glibc code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfscanf-internal.c.html#2537).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Clang [totally fails to output any meaningful diagnostics here](https://godbolt.org/z/4555Y), whereas GCC [knows exactly what is happening](https://godbolt.org/z/4555Yf) - so yet again GCC 1 - 0 Clang.

And as for the format string - well, it doesn't work. The format argument to `scanf` is a string. The string ends at terminating null, i.e. the format string you're giving to `scanf` is

```
scanf("%31[^", buf);
```

On my computer, compiling the program gives

```
% gcc scanf.c
scanf.c: In function ‘main’:
scanf.c:8:20: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format [-Wformat=]
    8 |     x = scanf("%31[^\0]", buf);
      |                    ^
scanf.c:8:21: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format [-Wformat-contains-nul]
    8 |     x = scanf("%31[^\0]", buf);
      |                     ^~
```

The scanset must have the closing right bracket `]`, otherwise the conversion specifier is invalid. If conversion specifier is invalid, the behaviour is undefined.

And, on my computer running it,

```
% printf 'foo\n\0bar' | ./a.out
x = 0, buf=
```

Q.E.D.

Comment: Isn't the question merely "why the compiler does not detect that the string with embedded `\0` is invalid?" Maybe I am misinterpreting it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that doesn't match the behaviour however, it seems it is doing *something* on OPs computer...

Comment: I guess the `-Wformat-contains-nul` edit is the actual QED :)

Comment: My question originally was "why does it work", and the correct answer is "it is undefined behavior and just appears to work".

Comment: @WilliamPursell maybe you should add the operating system

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm doing this on Macos, but since it's UB it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. clang on my computer outputs no diagnostics by default <3 yay for "clang has so much better diagnostics" :D

Comment: I'm on MacOS also, and wonder of wonders, I can reproduce William's behavior perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather strange situation.  I think there are a couple of things going on.

First of all, a string in C ends by definition at the first `\0`.  You can always scoff at this rule, for example by writing a string literal with an explicit `\0` in the middle of it.  When you do, though, the characters after the `\0` are mostly invisible.  Very few standard library functions are able to see them, because of course just about everything that interprets a C string will stop at the first `\0` it finds.

However: the string you pass as the first argument to `scanf` is typically parsed twice -- and by "parsed" I mean actually interpreted as a scanf format string possibly containing special `%` sequences.  It's always going to be parsed at run time, by the actual copy of `scanf` in your C run-time library.  But it's typically also parsed by the compiler, at compile time, so that the compiler can warn you if the % sequences don't match the actual arguments you call it with.  (The run-time library code for `scanf`, of course, is unable to perform this checking.)

Now, of course, there's a pretty significant potential problem here: what if the parsing performed by the compiler is in some way different than the parsing performed by the actual `scanf` code in the run-time library?  That might lead to confusing results.

And, to my considerable surprise, it looks like the scanf format parsing code in compilers *can* (and in some cases does) do something special and unexpected.  clang doesn't (it doesn't complain about the malformed string at all), but gcc says both "no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format" and "embedded ‘\0’ in format".  So it's noticing.

This is possible (though still surprising) because the compiler, at least, can see the whole string literal, and is in a position to notice that the null character is an explicit one inserted by the programmer, not the more usual implicit one appended by the compiler.  And indeed the warning "embedded ‘\0’ in format" emitted by gcc proves that gcc, at least, is quite definitely written to accommodate this possibility.  (See the footnote below for a bit more on the compiler's ability to "see" the whole string literal.)

But the second question is, why does it (seem to) work at runtime?  What is the actual `scanf` code in the C library doing?

That code, at least, has no way of knowing that the `\0` was explicit and that there are "real" characters following it.  That code simply must stop at the first `\0` that it finds.  So it's operating as if the format string was

```
"%31[^"
```

That's a malformed format string, of course.  The run-time library code isn't required to do anything reasonable.  But my copy, like yours, is able to read the full string "foo".  What's up with that?

My guess is that after seeing the `%` and the `[` and the `^`, and deciding that it's going to scan characters not matching some set, it's perfectly willing to, in effect, infer the missing `]`, and sail on matching characters from the scanset, which ends up having no excluded characters.

I tested this by trying the variant

```
    x = scanf("%31[^\0o]", buf);
```

This also matched and printed "foo", not "f".

Obviously things are nothing like guaranteed to work like this, of course.  @AnttiHaapala has already posted an answer showing that his C RTL declines to scan "foo" with the malformed scan string at all.

---

Footnote:
Most of the time, an embedded in `\0` in a string truly, prematurely ends it.  Most of the time, everything following the `\0` is effectively invisible, because at run time, every piece of string interpreting code will stop at the first `\0` it finds, with no way to know whether it was one explicitly inserted by the programmer or implicitly appended by the compiler.  But as we've seen, the compiler can tell the difference, because the compiler (obviously) *can* see the entire string literal, exactly as entered by the programmer.  Here's proof:

```
char str1[] = "Hello, world!";
char str2[] = "Hello\0world!";

printf("sizeof(str1) = %zu, strlen(str1) = %zu\n", sizeof(str1), strlen(str1));
printf("sizeof(str2) = %zu, strlen(str2) = %zu\n", sizeof(str2), strlen(str2));
```

Normally, `sizeof` on a string literal gives you a number one bigger than `strlen`.  But this code prints:

```
sizeof(str1) = 14, strlen(str1) = 13
sizeof(str2) = 13, strlen(str2) = 5
```

Just for fun I also tried:

```
char str3[5] = "Hello";
```

This time, though, `strlen` gave a larger number:

```
sizeof(str3) = 5, strlen(str3) = 10
```

I was mildly lucky.  `str3` has no trailing `\0`, neither one inserted by me nor appended by the compiler, so `strlen` sails off the end, and could easily have counted hundreds or thousands of characters before finding a random `\0` somewhere in memory, or crashing.

Comment: Let's just face it, clang has worse diagnostics :D

Answer (score 1):

> Why can a null character be embedded in a conversion specifier for scanf?

A *null character* cannot directly be specified as part of a *scanset* as in `"%31[^\0]"` as the parsing of the string ends with the first *null character*.

`"%31[^\0]"` is parsed by `scanf()` as if it was `"%31[^"`.  As it is an invalid `scanf()`
specifier, UB will likely follow.  A compiler may provide diagnostics on more than what `scanf()` sees.

---

A *null character* can be part of a *scanset* as in `"%31[^\n]"`.  This will read in all characters, including the *null character*, other than `'\n'`.

In the unusual case of reading *null chracters*, to determine the number of characters read scanned, use `"%n"`.

```
int n = 0;
scanf("%31[^\n]%n", buf, &n);
scanf("%*1[\n]"); // Consume any 1 trailing \n
if (n) {
  printf("First part of buf=%s, %d characters read ", buf, n);
}
```

Comment: @SteveSummit  Disagree with the hypothetical-ness and possible uses.  IAC, OP is certainly not a newbie.  This answers to a level that OP can handle.

Comment: @SteveSummit, I'm no C newbie, and I sometimes use `scanf` for things.  I don't handle character data with embedded null characters particularly frequently, but I would comfortable doing so.  I daresay C experts will be happy to use `scanf` when it is a good tool for the job. That may be rare, but not so rare as to be hypothetical.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, chux: Okay, I retract the comment.